# why print statement don't work as intended?

Tags: python

```
li=['ram', 12, 13, 'shyam']

>>> for i in li:
 ...     print(i)
... print("hi")

File "<stdin>", line 3
print("hi")
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm working on Ubuntu shell with Python-1.7.2 and trying to simply loop through a list and want to add a print statement at the end. But it raises exception as above.

I don't be able to understand why it raise above exception. As for loop reaches it's end and I simply add a print statement outside for loop.

Please! help me to figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running in interactive interpreter, you need to leave an empty line after a block to indicate the end of the block, otherwise the interpreter assumes that the lines that come after the block are part of the block, and through the `invalid syntax` error (Like it did in your case).

Example -

```
>>> for i in li:
...     print(i)
...                        # <---- notice the empty line
>>> print("hi")
```

Answer (score 3):

After completing the block, you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time.